# Use index scan instead of seq scan on transactions

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I have two tables i want to do a full text search on. Transaction and transaction line. The search is always bounded by from and to date which i can filter on transaction line.

Then I'd like to join filtered transaction lines with transaction, using pkey index. Then apply full text search on the resulting join.

The issue is that my query uses sequential scan on transaction.

Given this query

```
explain analyse with
    t as (select transaction.id, transaction.document as t_doc, transaction_line.document as tl_doc                          from transaction_line
left join transaction on transaction_id = transaction.id
where '2023-12-30' <= date and date <= '2023-12-31')
select id from t where t.t_doc @@ to_tsquery('norwegian', '2400') or
t.tl_doc @@ to_tsquery('norwegian', '2400');
```

Why does it result in a seq scan on transaction to join with transaction lines.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Hash Left Join  (cost=1301.31..2576.17 rows=36 width=8) (actual time=26.248..28.903 rows=23 loops=1)                           |
|  Hash Cond: (transaction_line.transaction_id = transaction.id)                                                                |
|  Filter: ((transaction.document @@ '''2400'''::tsquery) OR (transaction_line.document @@ '''2400'''::tsquery))                |
|  Rows Removed by Filter: 305                                                                                                  |
|  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction_line  (cost=12.79..1286.50 rows=439 width=55) (actual time=0.193..2.598 rows=328 loops=1)|
|        Recheck Cond: (('2023-12-30'::date <= date) AND (date <= '2023-12-31'::date))                                          |
|        Heap Blocks: exact=93                                                                                                  |
|        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on date_idx  (cost=0.00..12.68 rows=439 width=0) (actual time=0.135..0.135 rows=328 loops=1)     |
|              Index Cond: ((date >= '2023-12-30'::date) AND (date <= '2023-12-31'::date))                                      |
|  ->  Hash  (cost=1101.01..1101.01 rows=15001 width=63) (actual time=25.853..25.854 rows=15001 loops=1)                        |
|        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1531kB                                                                       |
|        ->  Seq Scan on transaction  (cost=0.00..1101.01 rows=15001 width=63) (actual time=0.025..19.925 rows=15001 loops=1)   |
|Planning Time: 5.917 ms                                                                                                        |
|Execution Time: 30.389 ms                                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd assume it would produce this execution plan:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=13.07..3293.88 rows=36 width=8) (actual time=0.399..6.457 rows=23 loops=1)                              |
|  Filter: ((transaction.document @@ '''2400'''::tsquery) OR (transaction_line.document @@ '''2400'''::tsquery))                      |
|  Rows Removed by Filter: 305                                                                                                        |
|  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction_line  (cost=12.79..1286.50 rows=439 width=55) (actual time=0.145..2.198 rows=328 loops=1)      |
|        Recheck Cond: (('2023-12-30'::date <= date) AND (date <= '2023-12-31'::date))                                                |
|        Heap Blocks: exact=93                                                                                                        |
|        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on date_idx  (cost=0.00..12.68 rows=439 width=0) (actual time=0.094..0.094 rows=328 loops=1)           |
|              Index Cond: ((date >= '2023-12-30'::date) AND (date <= '2023-12-31'::date))                                            |
|  ->  Index Scan using transaction_pkey on transaction  (cost=0.29..4.56 rows=1 width=63) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=328)|
|        Index Cond: (id = transaction_line.transaction_id)                                                                           |
|Planning Time: 1.905 ms                                                                                                              |
|Execution Time: 6.625 ms                                                                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit 09.11.23-10:20 ->
We don't have production data yet so these 15k transactions are estimated to be around 10M per year per schema. With around 20-30M transaction lines. Takes a bit of time to produce these amounts when we are required to fill every transaction with a sequence without holes.

So a 10M seq scan to find less than 10% of the transactions seems a bit expensive to me.

Comment: This seems like a pretty small difference to be concerned about.  You should run the plans with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and with track_io_timing turned on.  Have you assessed how the 2nd one does from a cold cache?

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for both tables?

Comment: DB fiddle with tables: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/10864

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the index scan is overpriced by the optimizer. Consider reducing `random_page_cost` or increasing `effective_cache_size` to values that match your hardware.

Comment: Could it be that insert order and dates are not realistic? Transactions and transaction lines in actual data should be inserted in a somewhat chronological order. Could this cause optimizer to look at random_page_cost as high? If they were inserted chronologically, then the query would make sense?

Also if i remove the full text search filter, it doesn't use sequential scan, it uses indexes. So I wonder if the query combination with filters on different index types messes with postgres?

Comment: I don't think that has an effect. That is just about the type of disk and the amount of RAM you have.